# Exponentiation associative in integers $\mod n$?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $b \in\mathbb Z, k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb Z_+\cup \{0\}$

We have the rules:

$$b^{k_1}\cdot b^{k_2} = b^{k_1 + k_2}$$
$$(b^{k_1})^{k_2} = b^{k_1k_2}$$

If we wanted to show the same association in $\mathbb Z/ m\mathbb Z$, is it sufficient to say the following using the definition of modular multiplication?

$$[b^{k_1}]m \cdot [b^{k_2}]m = [b^{k_1} \cdot b^{k_2}]m = [b^{k_1 + k_2}]m$$

I feel like this isn't rigorous enough or there is a more correct way to show this?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the first is a distributive law. Exponentiation is inherently not associative since $ a^{b^c} \neq ((a^b)^c) = a^{bc} $. The second is the power to a power law of course, I'm not quite sure if that is distributive but it isn't an associative law exactly.

Perhaps a more rigorous way to do the proof ( although no less correct) would be to show that exponentiation is repeated multiplication, and then let it hold for that case. At least that is the typical approach.

So,

$$ b^{k_1} * b^{k_2} \equiv \underbrace{(b * b * \dots * b)}_\text{k_1 times} * \underbrace{(b * b * \dots * b)}_\text{k_2 times}  \equiv \underbrace{(b * b * \dots * b * b * b * \dots * b) }_\text{k_1 + k_2 times}\equiv b^{k_1 + k_2}$$

We use associativity of multiplication here and the repeated definition of exponentiation.

For the power to a power,
$$ (b^{k_1})^{k_2} \equiv \underbrace{b^{k_1} * b^{k_1} * \dots * b^{k_1}}_\text{k_2 times} \equiv b^{k_1 * k_2} $$

The only advantage of the way its done here is that it is done from the modular definitions of operations as in abstract algebra, and not merely reducing from the integers, although I see no reason why that isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Since $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$, exponentiation to these powers is simply multiplication that many times, so we can use induction on the analogous property for multiplication

$$[a]m\cdot[b]m=[a\cdot b]m$$